# How to access Historical Data from The Weather Company (TWC) using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX)

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science-experience

I'm using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX), https://datascience.ibm.com/. I use R with RStudio.

1. What's the lowest level of data available (say, seconds or minutes or hourly, ...)?
2. Looking for an example code to access lowest level of data say for the period 1 January 2016 to 31 November 2017 for a certain location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per API documentation historical data only gives last 24 hours of data
https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/#!/Historical_Data/v1geotimeseriesobs

Anyhow here is the implementation for R and Rstudio to get data for last 23 hours in a dataframe for latitude and longitude(33.40/-83.42):-

```
library(jsonlite)
username <- "<PUT-YOUR-WEATHERDATA-USERNAME>"
password <- "<PUT-YOUR-WEATHERDATA-PASSWORD>"
base <- "https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/observations/timeseries.json?hours=23"

library(httr)
get_data <- GET(base, authenticate(username,password, type = "basic"))
get_data
get_data_text <- content(get_data, "text")
get_data_text
get_data_json <- fromJSON(get_data_text,flatten = TRUE)
get_data_json
get_data_df <- as.data.frame(get_data_json)
View(get_data_df)
```

Comment: What procedure, I need to follow to get long term historical data from TWC.